# Knockoutjs2 observable binding doesn't show updated value

Tags: knockout.js, 2-way-object-databinding

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var initialData = <%= new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model) %>;
 var viewModel = {
 variables: ko.observable(initialData.Variables),
 //...
};
$(document).ready(function(){ko.applyBindings(viewModel);});
</script>


<body>
<table data-bind="with:variables">
<tr><td><input data-bind="value: description"/></td></tr>
<tr><td><input data-bind="value: description"/></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

When updating the first row, the second row is not updated.  What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Each of the properties needs to be an observable itself.  Check out ko.mapping.fromJS.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing I had to add was the knockout.mapping.js